# Vagrant up hangs at "ssh auth method: private key"

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I've been having some issues getting vagrant version 1.8.1 to run with virtualbox 5.0.10, box precise64. My operating system is Windows 7.

Essentially, when I run

```
vagrant up
```

...[this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BHbM.png)

So far, I've attempted the following:

opening another command line and running a myriad of different codes, including:

```
vagrant ssh
vagrant ssh-config
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

I've also attempted the fix shown on this video (to no avail)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDQpfb0eFTc

As well as manually specifying the ssh key, and changing the ssh key.

My attempts to ssh into the box manually are met with a "connection refused" error.

When I open the VM GUI through virtualbox, it stops at the login page, rather than the boot menu others have reported.

My vagrantfile is unmodified, however I've attempted all of the above with additions:

```
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
```

.. which didn't work

I also attempted adding this (with and without the above Vagrantfile additions)

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = "C:/Users/Luka/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
```

Which also gave me nothing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal Vagrantfile that causes this issue for you? Then we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: This occurs with an unmodified Vagrantfile. I've added some strategies I approached this with as well.

Comment: So are you running `vagrant init hashicorp/trusty64` to generate the Vagrantfile?

Comment: `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64`

Comment: Ah, right... precise. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: I just ran `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` followed by `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` without any issues on Linux and Mac hosts (Vagrant 1.8.1 and VirtualBox 5.0.14). I don't have a Windows box, so I can't try to reproduce this with your setup. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: Thank you for trying, at least!

Comment: Facing this on mac. The solution given does not help.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old topic, but I ran into the same issue and for me the solution was to **enable the Hardware virtualization in BIOS (VT-x)**, which is required on Windows OS to run any kind of virtual machine.

I hope this will help someone who stumbles into this.

Comment: Great information. I only happened to see that this was the issue after I manually launched VirtualBox GUI and tried to start the created guest system.

Answer (score 7):

I spent multiple hours trying to troubleshoot this issue, and tried every solution listed above and more, and I wasn't getting anywhere.

The error I was getting when running `vagrant up`:

```
[...]
default: Booting VM...
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
[...]
```

I decided to pursue this event I was seeing in the VirtualBox log for my running VM:

```
00:00:01.752390 HM: HMR3Init: Attempting fall back to NEM: VT-x is not available
```

When I saw that, I decided to check using the "Intel Processor Identification Utility" (from Intel's website) to verify if VT-x was enabled or not. To my surprise, it showed that "Intel Virtualization Technology" was disabled:

[image]

I was pretty sure VT-x was enabled in my BIOS, but I checked again to make sure. Indeed, VT-x was enabled in my BIOS.

Pretty stumped by what I was seeing, I kept looking on the internet as to why VT-x was enabled in BIOS, but showing as disabled by the OS. A lot of articles kept pointing at "Hyper-V" being the culprit. So I uninstalled "Hyper-V" using the Windows Features utility [as well as my Docker Desktop" because it relies on Hyper-V to function], but the Intel CPU identification utility kept showing VT-x as disabled.

Next thing I tried was to remove all the items that are identified as "interfering" with Hyper-V in the Windows 10 "Windows Features" [listed as "Turn Windows features on or off" in the search bar]. The items in red are the ones I removed:

1. Containers
2. Hyper-V
3. Virtual Machine Platform
4. Windows Hypervisor Platform
5. Windows Subsystem for Linux

[image]

I restarted my PC, again, I checked the status of VT-x with the CPU identification utility, and still, it was disabled.

At this point I was pretty much going to throw the towel at the issue until I found some article where someone ran this command manually in an elevated command prompt (cmd.exe):

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

I restarted my PC, checked the status of VT-x with the CPU identification utility, to my surprise it was showing as ENABLED!!:

[image]

When I checked the VirtualBox logs from my running VM after VT-x showed as enabled, I could see the following event instead:

```
00:00:01.556258 HM: HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging and unrestricted guest execution hw support
```

In my command-line window, after `vagrant up`, I could now see:

```
default: Booting VM...
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default:
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default:
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
default: Machine booted and ready!
```

My solution in a nutshell?

Make sure the OS sees VT-x as enabled using a utility such as "Intel Processor Identification Utility" [Or whatever utility depending on your CPU architecture]. I believe there is a bug in Windows 10 that causes this issue, but I haven't been able to put my finger on it (and I don't have time to do so). It seems Hyper-V is the root cause of all the issues. For the people concerned about not being able to use Docker Desktop anymore, I believe there are alternatives out there for non-Hyper-V solutions (i.e. free Docker EE??).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me a lot. I also spent some time searching for the problem, only with this post I could really solve my problem...

Comment: Thanks! I really had to disable everything related to VMs as you suggested, despite having VT-x enabled in BIOS - only then it worked.

Comment: I have it working with "windows subsystem for Linux" being "on"

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me with "ubuntu/focal64". I tried different solutions, but nothing worked.
Switch box to "ubuntu/xenial64" - everything loads successfully.

My setup:
win10 home 10.0.19041 Build 19041
vagrant 2.2.9
virtualbox 6.2

Answer (score 3):

I am on:

- Windows 10
- Vagrant 2.2.19
- Virtualbox 6.1.30

I have been using laravel homestead for a long time.

A co-worker recently recommended I try docker. After installing docker desktop & configuring my machine to use WSL, I experimented with Laravel Sail over the weekend.

Then I tried to `vagrant up` into my normal homestead machine this morning, but my system would hang at `default: SSH auth method: private key`

After trying several of the other solutions above and elsewhere, here's what finally worked for me:

1. Open Oracle VM VirtualBox manager
2. File > Host Network Manager
3. Select "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"
4. Click "Remove"
5. Switch to your normal terminal of choice and run `vagrant up` as ususal

The system will re-build the network adapter and the vagrant machine will boot up as normal. Back to work.

Credits: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11987#issuecomment-903666254

And: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56318621

Answer (score 2):

I also got this issue when I am trying to use *laravel/homestead* vagrant box. For me, I found out that the issue is caused by WindowsFeature **VirtualMachinePlatform**. I have enabled it since I am using WSL 2 in my machine. Simply disabling that feature helped with the issue.

To disable the **VirtualMachinePlatform** feature, open PowerShell as an Administrator and run:

```
dism.exe /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:VirtualMachinePlatform /NoRestart
```

Then **Restart** your machine and try **vagrant up**. It worked for me.

You can enable the  **VirtualMachinePlatform** feature again by simply running the below command on PowerShell as an Administrator:

```
dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /NoRestart
```

Then **Restart** your machine again and the feature is enabled again.

I have reported an **issue** regarding this also. If anyone needs to keep track on that bug [click here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11987)

Comment: I installed Docker Desktop and tried to enable WSL. This solved my issue. Can't use Docker Desktop however which is fine.

Comment: But for using Docker desktop with WSL we should have enabled it in the windows settings, right? When the WSL is enabled we can still face that issue I think.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me with box `ubuntu/bionic64` too. By switching to `ubuntu/trusty64` it runs without a problem. (Win10 Pro v2004 build 19041.572)

As state [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11777#issuecomment-661076612) there is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1829625) that causes some of the newer Ubuntu boxes to boot slowly, which is causing the SSH timeout in this case.
You can work around this by adding the following customizations to your Vagrantfile:

```rb
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", "4"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file", File::NULL]
end
```

Comment: This worked for me using 'ubuntu/focal64'

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days of trying to solve the problem with "SSH auth method: private key", it was found that windows 10 has a conflict with vagrant.

As a tool to validate the status of virtualization, the program was used: "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/12136/28539/intel-processor-identification-utility-windows-version .html "

I show you the capture of the initial state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7toz.png

Fix it by disabling the following windows features: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTURj.png

Once the aforementioned features were deactivated and the computer was restarted, I share the new state of the processor where it is evident that virtualization is already working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOxAx.png

PS: On saying that you already activate virtualization on the board (bios)

With this solution already vagrant works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to try this too if other ways didn't help yet.

In VirtualBox go to **Settings**, click on **Network**, then on **Advance**, then change your *Network type* to : **Intel PRO/1000 MT Server** (82545EM) and **refresh** the MAC-address

[image]

Make sure your **Port Forwarding** is set to default like this image:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps someone as I struggled with mine for quite some time after upgrading Virtualbox, clearly I did not investigate very well due to time constraints, then after reading quite a few posts, decided to clear my known_hosts file on my machine, the the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score -3):

I have also faced the issue “Vagrant up hangs at ssh auth method: private key”, after trying out a lot off stuff. But as stated above by morkitz Enabling the Hardware Virtualization solved my issue as well.

My Stack was
1. Win 8.1 Enterprise
2. Vagrant 2.1.2
3. Virtual Box 5.2.18